# plot function type

Tags: r

For digits I have done so:

```
digits <- c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
```

Comment: `stri_count_fixed("we are friends!","!")`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `[:punct:]` to detect punctuation. This detects

```
[!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]
```

Either in `grepexpr`

```
x = c("we are friends!, Good Friends!!")
gregexpr("[[:punct:]]", x)
R> gregexpr("[[:punct:]]", x)
[[1]]
[1] 15 16 30 31
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

or via `stringi`

```
# Gives 4
stringi::stri_count_regex(x, "[:punct:]")
```

Notice the `,` is counted as punctuation.

---

The question seems to be about getting individual counts of particular punctuation marks. @Joba provides a neat answer in the comments:

```
## Create a vector of punctuation marks you are interested in 
punct = strsplit('[]?!"\'#$%&(){}+*/:;,._`|~[<=>@^-]\\', '')[[1]]
```

The count how often they appear
    counts = stringi::stri_count_fixed(x, punct)

Decorate the vector

```
setNames(counts, punct)
```

Comment: I think OP wants a count for each punctuation.

Comment: Which is what this answer gives

Comment: "A count for each punctuation" = a vector of how many !, how many ?, etc. separately. Similar to his digits example.

Comment: With this code I get only a amount of punctuation marks. But how can I get a count for each punctuation?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `punct <- strsplit('[]?!"\'#$%&(){}+*/:;,._\`|~[<=>@^-]\\', '')[[1]]; counts <- stringi::stri_count_fixed("amdfa,!!!\"\\ ad,a, ad,. ", punct); setNames(counts, punct)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions.

```
stringi::stri_count_regex("amdfa, ad,a, ad,. ", "[:punct:]")
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

might help too.