# vector of punctuation

Tags: r, punctuation

For digits I can write a vector like this:

```
digits <- c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
```

How can I get an analogous vector of punctuation marks?

Comment: What is your expected output about the `vector of punctuation`.  I meant the order of elements

Comment: Are you looking for a vector of all non number or letter characters?

Comment: Isn’t this just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792866/counting-punctuation-marks-in-text?

Comment: Is this vector being used to search for punctuation in other text?

Comment: Which locale? C++ uses !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_{|}~ (along with the back-tick that I forget how to escape in SO text boxes) for the `C` locale in `ispunct()`, but punctuation sets are locale-dependent.

Comment: did you mean to edit your question to its current form, where it doesn't actually contain a question at all ... ?  I would roll back the edit, but possibly you made a mistake and would like to fix it yourself?

Comment: now I'm confused -- this is getting worse. I will come back in a little while and roll back to the original if it seems necessary ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could convert numbers to punctuation using Unicode code points (thanks Konrad, for point that out).

```
strsplit(intToUtf8(c(33:47, 58:64, 91:96)), "")[[1]]
# [1] "!"  "\"" "#"  "$"  "%"  "&"  "'"  "("  ")"  "*"  "+"  ","  "-"  "." 
#[15] "/"  ":"  ";"  "<"  "="  ">"  "?"  "@"  "["  "\\" "]"  "^"  "_"  "`"
```

some Ethiopian punctuation (`0x1361:0x1367`):

```
strsplit(intToUtf8(0x1361:0x1367), "")[[1]]
[1] "፡" "።" "፣" "፤" "፥" "፦" "፧"
```

If this is missing punctuation you want to use, you can look up the unicode points associated with the punctuation you want, and use it (e.g. somewhere like http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm). You can also get the integers from `utf8ToInt`.  For instance "~" isn't included above:

```
utf8ToInt("~")
#[1] 126
```